# Cucumber: How to pass an entire example table as value to another example table in each iteration

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am trying to find out if there is a work around for my validation here. Have replaced actual steps with something similar.

Is it possible to define example tables ,, and pass the entire table as data to each iteration ?

I have huge list of sub elements to be verified and so I do not want to define  sub element data in each iteration separated by a delimiter .

Here is the sample scenario

```
ScenarioOutLine: Validate POST call for XXX to have valid sub elements under each element 

Given Request headers are set 
When Request is posted
Then the response body content has element <ele_name> with sub elements <Sub_ele>

Examples:
|elem_name>|<Sub_ele>|
|Dept|{Dept_Sub_elements}|
|Subject|{Subject_Sub_elements}
|Course|{Course_Sub_elements}|

Examples:
|Dept_Sub_Elements|
|IT|
|Marketing|

Examples:
|Subject_Sub_Elements|
|Anatomy|
|Physciology|
|Management,economics|
```

Answer (score 1):

I would hide all the mandatory verifications in the steps, in a method I always call after each scenario, and not pollute my feature files with it. The mandatory elements should always be there. They are not important when you discuss what the system actually does that the end users really care about.

BDD and Cucumber is all about communication and nothing about testing.

I always work hard on hiding the technical details I my scenarios as they need to be understood by the business representatives. Technical details belong among the steps or helper code that the steps delegate to. Your mandatory elements are a technical detail from my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataTable after the desired Given, When, or Then step.
see reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#data-tables

Depending on the language you are using you should be able to find the examples online. Here is an example of specflow:

[Having Tables in Example Table in SpecFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200405/having-tables-in-example-table-in-specflow)

If you have huge data tables (hundreds of rows) then you can think about saving the data in different file (property file, json file, or even excel file)

For smaller tables, they can be mentioned in .feature files. To make it easier to read, you can use table formatter plugins for intellij or eclipse. 
e.g. 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7550-pipe-table-formatter

Comment: if you have huge tables to validate you should perhaps ask yourself why you are using Cucumber for this (since you're clearly not benefiting from the BDD aspect or a discussion around the feature file) and not just using something like a unit test framework to run these tests.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a single example table as an input to the validation step?  Since nothing from the examples table is altering the given or when statements, there is no value to running this scenario multiple times.

Even if you were running it multiple times, I see no value to what you are trying to do, and it just makes it harder for humans to make any sense of the examples.  Given the entire point of BDD is to have a conversation with stakeholders around the feature file and the scenarios there, anything which makes it harder for humans to understand the examples is generally a bad smell where BDD and Cucumber are concerned.  Thus there is negative value in terms of trying to DRY out tables

```
Then the resulting page should have <Sub_element> found under <Element>:
  | <Element> | <Sub_element>        |
  | Dept      | IT                   |
  | Dept      | Marketing            |
  | Subject   | Anatomy              |
  | Subject   | Physciology          |
  | Subject   | Management,Economics |
  | Course    | CompSci 210          |
  | Course    | Math 101             |
```